# jquery search text box: how to ignore few list repeated elements while searching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of countries from which user can select one country. We have few countries that need to be at the top of the display list. After these countries are displayed on top, we have normal alphabetic ordering of countries.

But the countries at the top comes again in the alphabetic order due to which they appear twice when user search for them.For example- India comes at top and also in alphabetic order. So when user types "Ind", there are two results shown which is confusing to the user.

We are using normal jquery string match and doing show/hide on li based on user input as follow to search user input in the list:

```
  $('#s').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.countryList>li').each(function(){
     var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();            
   });
  });
```

How can I keep these duplicate entries and only show one instance when someone search for them.

Here is the link for fiddle-
[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35d2woec/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try keeping track of which countries you have found already in an array and if they were already found, then hide them.

```
$('#s').keyup(function(){
   var foundCountries = [];
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.countryList>li').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

        if(!text.inArray(foundCountries) && text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) {
              $(this).show();
              foundCountries.push(text);
        } else {
              $(this).hide();
        }      
   });
});
```

Comment: I made some alterations going with @Keith.Abramo idea. Looks sloppy, but still get's the job done.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/35d2woec/1/)
I also replaced == 0 with !== -1 as single character searches were not working properly for me with that.